# Accessing data from API with Angular (formatting error?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli-v6

The data I am trying to access from the API is formatted like below:

```
{
  “array1”:[
    {"id”:1, ”someProperty”:”A"},
    {"id":2, "someProperty”:”B”}
  ],
  “array2”:[
    {"id”:1, ”anotherProperty”:”foo”, ”lastProperty”:”foo2”},
    {"id":2, "anotherProperty”:”bar”, ”lastProperty”:”bar2”}
  ]                                                                      
}
```

The Dependencies class:

```
import { FirstArray } from './first-array';
import { SecondArray } from './second-array';
export class Dependencies {
  constructor(
    public array1: Array<FirstArray>,
    public array2: Array<SecondArray>
  ) {  }
}
```

The FirstArray class:

```
export class FirstArray {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public someProperty: string
  ) {  }
}
```

The SecondArray class:

```
export class SecondArray {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public anotherProperty: string,
    public lastProperty: string
  ) {  }
}
```

My Dependencies service.ts file:

```
/** GET all Dependencies from the server */
getAllDependencies (): Observable<Dependencies[]> {
return this.http.get<Dependencies[]>(apiUrl).pipe(
    tap(allDependencies => this.log('fetched allDependencies')),
    catchError(this.handleError('getAllDependencies', []))
  );
}
```

The component.ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllDependencies();
  console.log("allDependencies:",this.allDependencies); 
}

allDependencies: Dependencies[];

getAllDependencies(): void {
  this.DependenciesService.getAllDependencies()
  .subscribe(allDependencies => this.allDependencies = allDependencies);
}
```

When I try console.log(this.allDependencies) in the component file, the result is undefined. The data is retrieved from the API correctly- 'fetched allDependencies' is printed in the logs, and I can print the Dependencies object in the logs just fine by stringifying from the service file:

```
/** GET all Dependencies from the server */
getAllDependencies (): Observable<Dependencies[]> {
return this.http.get<Dependencies[]>(apiUrl).pipe(
    tap(allDependencies => this.log(JSON.stringify(allDependencies))),
    catchError(this.handleError('getAllDependencies', []))
  );
}
```

My question: how can I access this data from my component file? I think I'm missing something in my data structures somewhere, or I have a Typescript-related error, but I am not sure.

Comment: The parameter is called `allDependencies` but you're logging `allLocDependencies`...

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo in the question. I am logging allDependencies in my code

Comment: The getAllDependencies method is asynchronous, you get the result when you subscribe. If you log before or afterwards you may not get it.

Comment: Can you update the question with your actual code then please?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: @Ric how can I access the data from the getAllDependencies method? When should I log?

Comment: Call then method from your service within ngOnInit in your component. Just add an extra line within the subscribe for the log.

Comment: When debugging something like this, either use batarang or temporarily put something in your constructor to access your component from the console (i.e. `window['MYCOMPONENT'] = this;`) and check on the values using the chrome dev console.  It is probably an issue because you're attempting to access the value outside the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue you have is that within your component, the method that calls your service is `void` and doesn't return anything...

It doesn't really add any value, so remove it and access the data like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.DependenciesService.getAllDependencies()
    .subscribe(allDependencies => {
     this.allDependencies = allDependencies;
     console.log(this.allDependencies); // multi-line with log.
    });    
}
```

**Updated as per your comment:**

Change your method from `getAllDependencies(): void` to `getAllDependencies(): Observable<Dependencies[]>` and call within `ngOnOnit`

```
getAllDependencies(): Observable<Dependencies[]> {
    return this.DependenciesService.getAllDependencies();
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllDependencies().subscribe(.....);
}
```

Comment: First: this works to display all the necessary data in the logs! Second: I updated my question again- I call the getAllDependencies method with ngOnInit, but the allDependencies object remains stubbornly undefined. How does your code define allDependencies, while mine doesn't?

Comment: because. your method is void and the service is asynchrounsly returning data, so your method probably finishes before the data is returned hence the variable remains unassigned. call the service method directly and remove the component method `getAllDependencies(): void`

Comment: Oh, okay. If I understand correctly, there is no way I can set the variable with a separate method in my component file, because the service method is asynchronous?

Comment: You can do it your way, in another method, but return the observable so that you can subscribe to it. Then all should work. I just didn't see it adding value.

Comment: I am not too familiar with how to do that, would you mind showing me/directing me somewhere I can read up on it?